# Como leer información proveniente de un dispositivo bluetooth previamente conectado al smartphone con Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, bluetooth

Me gustaría leer información proveniente de un dispositivo bluetooth previamente conectado al smartphone.

He leído un poco y no se si entiendo mal, pero siempre obtengo información sobre como hacer un scanner bluetooth dentro de mi aplicación, por lo que primero me pide obtener un lista de dispositivos disponibles para luego conectarme a el.  Pero yo no busco conectarme desde la app sino que solo leer datos de un dispositivo previamente conectado, no desde la app que estoy desarrollando sino que desde el smartphone propiamente tal.

Entonce mi pregunta es, de que manera obtengo el dispositivo ya conectado? como lo indentifico

Me disculpo de antemano por mi bajo conocimiento en el tema, soy relativamente nuevo en esta área.

muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: La pregunta es demasiado amplia (revisar [ask]), te recomiendo inicies con la identificación del dispositivo, en el sitio puedes encontrar información: https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+bluetooth